# I want to use the code . command inside WSL to open vs-code-insiders with remote

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I'm using Windows Subsystem for linux and the best text editor experience so far has been VS Code- Insiders with their WSL remote addon. However, despite repeated efforts I've only had partial success in replicating the functionality where within my WSL (zsh) terminal I can type `code .` or `code XX` to open a directory in code. I do have a function that works, opening the WSL directory in code insiders, but it does not go through the WSL interface somehow so I am using a powershell/ windows environment where I wanted all linux. This function works to some degree, and is provided.

I tried a simple alias (didn't work because of windows spaces in directory path). This version works - but I then have to `ctrl + shift + p` -> `Remote WSL: Reopen Window In WSL`.

```sh
function code(){
/mnt/c/Users/camer/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code\ Insiders/Code\ -\ Insiders.exe $1
}
```

I'd like the function to work as expected - when run within WSL it opens the windows (.exe) VSCode insiders with a WSL session already.

Comment: Does putting double quotes around $1 help?

Comment: @Roadowl I initially dismissed your comment - but I tried it just now and actually "$1" does make the function work as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting double quotes around $1.

Always double quote references to variables that are paths or filenames.

Answer (score 0):

@Roadowl answered my question in the comments above. For reference I will paste the fixed function for copy/paste. Just change the directory to your path to Insiders on windows.

```sh
function code(){
/mnt/c/Users/camer/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code\ Insiders/Code\ -\ Insiders.exe "$1"
}
```

Comment: I just made the comment an 'official' answer.